# AVI merging with FFmpeg truncated

Tags: ffmpeg

I was using FFmpeg to merge two avi files which were converted to AVI from wmv. The conversion from wmv to avi worked fine, but when I am going to merge those two avi files, some part of the longer video is truncated. Also if the first video is without sound, then the merged video is not containing sound at all. What may be the fix? Please anybody with FFmpeg expertise, help me.

## Note: Command for merging

ffmpeg -isync -i "concat:file1.avi|file2.avi" -f avi -c copy merged.avi

Thanks in advance

Comment: what options and args are you using?

Comment: ffmpeg -isync -i "concat:file1.avi|file2.avi" -f avi -c copy merged.avi

Comment: hello, anybody can you please help?